# How to display Array elements on UITextView, Swift3 & Parse server (bitnami)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, parse-platform

I'm newbie swift/Parse server and was struggling to display array elements stored in Parse server(`bitnami`).

It works as I wanted finally, but it looks super strange and I can't understand why it works well.

Is there anyone who can understand why it works?

1. ViewController.swift

   ```
   query?.limit = 1

   query?.findObjectsInBackground(block: {(objects,error) in
       if let users = objects {

           for object in users {

               if let user = object as? PFUser {

                   self.userName.text = user.username!


                   if let userCarType = user["carType"] as? Array<Any>{


                       self.carTypeText.text = userCarType[0] as! String


                   }
   ```
2. Parse server

Column : carType (Array)

Value  : "Toyota,Ford"

3. How it displays on UITextField:

Toyota,Ford

Answer (score 0):

Below is some explanation of the code, please let me know if you need more explaining.

```
    let query = PFQuery(className:"UserCarTypes") /// name of your table
    query.includeKey("UserPointer") // if you have pointers like user (and you want to load this data also)
    query.whereKey("x", equalTo: false) // set some conditions in query if needed
    query.findObjectsInBackground { (objects: [PFObject]?, error: Error?) in

        // query always returns the objects (rows) in a [PFObject] array

        // first check for error or nil
        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
            return
        }

        if objects?.count == 0 || objects == nil {
            print("no data retrieved")
            return
        }

        //loop throught objects
        if let users = objects {
            for object in users {

                //set user label
                if let user = object as? PFUser {
                    self.userName.text = user.username! // set username on text label (this assumes there is always a username, otherwise your app will crash)

                }

                //set carType label
                if let userCarType = user["carType"] as? NSArray { // downcast the row data from the PFObject to an Array
                    if let first_car = userCarType[0] as? String { // set the first value of your array of userCarType: Toyota
                        if let second_car = userCarType[1] as? String { // set the second value of your array: Ford
                            self.carTypeText.text = "\(first_car),\(second_car)" // set both car types on the TextLabel
                        } else {
                            self.carTypeText.text = "\(first_car)" // set only the first car type on the TextLabel
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```